# Simultaneous Equations with given conditions

Tags: python, scipy

to start off I have already solved this problem so it's not a big deal, I'm just asking to satisfy my own curiosity. The question is how to solve a series of simultaneous equations given a set of constraints. The equations are:

```
tau = 62.4*d*0.0007
A = (b + 1.5*d)*d
P = b + 2*d*sqrt(1 + 1.5**2)
R = A/P
Q = (1.486/0.03)*A*(R**(2.0/3.0))*(0.0007**0.5)
```

and the conditions are:
tau <= 0.29, Q = 10000 +- say 3, and minimize b

As I mentioned I was already able to come up with a solution using a series of nested loops:

```
    b = linspace(320, 330, 1000)
    d = linspace(0.1, 6.6392, 1000)
    ansQ = []
    ansv = []
    anstau = []
    i_index = []
    j_index = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        for j in range(len(d)):
            tau = 62.4*d[j]*0.0007
            A = (b[i] + 1.5*d[j])*d[j]
            P = b[i] + 2*d[j]*sqrt(1 + 1.5**2)
            R = A/P
            Q = (1.486/0.03)*A*(R**(2.0/3.0))*(0.0007**0.5)
            if Q >= 10000 and tau <= 0.29:
                ansQ.append(Q)
                ansv.append(Q/A)
                anstau.append(tau)
                i_index.append(i)
                j_index.append(j)
```

This takes a while, and there is something in the back of my head saying that there must be an easier/more elegant solution to this problem. Thanks (Linux Mint 13, Python 2.7.x, scipy 0.11.0)

Comment: Posts that begin "I already have an answer ..." are generally better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: b can be anything, that's part of the problem. I could combine all the equations, but I'll still have 2 variables with an infinite number of solutions. The answer comes in the constraints. I could try it but I'm not sure it would help.

Comment: Your constraints still give you an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: right but minimizing b given Q = 10000 gives one solution. I said +- 3 just to say that doesn't need to be exactly 10000 but that is the target.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only have two degrees of freedom here---you can rewrite everything in terms of `b` and `d` or `b` and `tau` or (pick your two favorites). Your constraint on `tau` implies directly a constraint on `d`, and you can use your constraint on `Q` to imply a constraint on `b`.

And it doesn't look (to me at least, I still haven't finished my coffee) that your code is doing anything other than plotting some two dimensional functions over a grid you've defined--NOT solving a system of equations. I normally understand "solving" to involve setting something equal to something else, and writing one variable as a function of another variable.

It does appear you've only posted a snippet, though, so I'll assume you do something else with your data down stream.

---

Ok, I see. I think this isn't really a minimization problem, it's a plotting problem. The first thing I'd do is see what ranges are implied for `b` and `d` from your constraints on `tau`, and then use that to derive a constraint on `d`. Then you can mesh those points with meshgrid (as you mentioned below) and run over all combinations.

Since you're applying the constraint before you apply the mesh (as opposed to after, as in your code), you'll only be sampling the parameter space that you're interested in. In your code you generate a bunch of junk you're not interested in, and pick out the gems. If you apply your constraints first, you'll only be left with gems!

I'd define my functions like:

```
P = lambda b, d: b + 2*d*np.sqrt(1 + 1.5**2)
```

which works like

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> P = lambda b, d: b + 2*d*np.sqrt(1 + 1.5**2)
>>> P(1,2)
8.2111025509279791
```

Then you can write another function to serve up `b` and `d` for you, so you can do something like:

```
def get_func_vals(b, d):
    pvals.append(P(b,d))
```

or, better yet, store `b` and `d` as tuples in a function that doesn't `return` but `yield`s:

```
pvals = [P(b,d) for (b,d) in thing_that_yields_b_and_d_tuples]
```

I didn't test this last line of code, and I always screw up these parenthesis, but I think it's right.

Comment: Of course, the Devil's advocate in me thinks that you know all this, and you're fishing for hints without wanting to appear to do so.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to optimize this type of problem. Perhaps Numpy's meshgrid function would help.

Comment: No not doing anything else with it down stream. This was a homework problem for a hydraulics class (open channel flow) and the goal was to find the dimensions of the channel (b and d) using the given equations and constraints.

Comment: That looks promising. Unfortunately I need to head to school here in a few minutes. I'll look at it this evening. I think you might be on to something there.